# How to search LinkedList<T> collection?

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have a `LinkedList<T>` object where T is an arbitrary object which has a property named ID. I want search my collection using ID as search criteria.

Now I know I can search it using a while loop:

```
LinkedListNode<MyObject> element = myObject.First;
while (element != myObject.Last)
{
    if (element.Value.ID == myID)
    break;

    element = element.Next;
}
```

But I'm wondering if there is a more elegant solution. Note that I need `LinkedListNode<T>` as a result in order to navigate the list from there.

Comment: None of the answers, so far, are any good. If you want to do this efficiently, use `yield` within your loop. Make an extension method out of it if you want to invoke it without a lot of code. You'll be iterating over the collection one way or another.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can write an extension method to get you a sequence of the nodes and search that:

```
public static IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<T>> Nodes<T>(this LinkedList<T> list)
{
    for (var node = list.First; node != null; node = node.Next)
    {
        yield return node;
    }
}
```

then you can do

```
var matchingNode = list.Nodes().FirstOrDefault(n => n.Value.Id == myId);
```

Comment: This doesn't looks readable. Earlier version was better after my edit. Any reason for this approach?

Comment: How do you get `IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<T>>` from the `LinkedList` in order to invoke this method?

Comment: @KeithPayne - I don't understand your question - `Nodes` returns the `IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<T>>` from the linked list.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - Sorry I was editing at the same time as you and didn't realise `Last.Next` can be null if the list is non-empty.

Comment: You don't need to check list.Count

Comment: Thanks. It confirmed my suspicion that I can't do what I want without the loop. Is this a flaw of linked list collection? Should LINQ methods return IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<T>>??

Comment: @Nezreli - Yes, it would be nice if `LinkedList<T>` implemented `IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<T>>` as well. I don't know why it doesn't, possibly to remove confusion since it is mainly viewed as a collection of `T`, not a collection of nodes.

Comment: How could I query a nested LinkedList using this helper? I will post my results if I get it working. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Same idea as Lee, but simpler code:

```
    public static IEnumerable<LinkedListNode<T>> Nodes<T>(this LinkedList<T> list)
    {
        var node = list.First;
        while (node != null)
        {
            yield return node;
            node = node.Next;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

No need to use LINQ or extension methods. Simply use .Find() - it returns a LinkedListNode

```
var node = list.Find(5);
```

Note: For this to work your model with the id would need to override object.Equals to compare ID's (and therefore object.GetHashCode)

Comment: The Find(T) method expects a reference to MyObject which I don't have.

Answer (score 1):

Will this give the result you expect?

Use @MartinLiversage answer and expand it to use the `Find` method which is part of the `LinkedList<T>`

```
int id = 1;
LinkedListNode<IHaveID> nodes = null;
LinkedList<IHaveID> testList = new LinkedList<IHaveID>();

var item = testList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == id);
if(item != null)
{
    nodes = testList.Find(item);
}
```

Comment: It's correct but it iterates the list twice which is not optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a single line property you can add to a `LinkedList<T>` inheriting class that will return the first element it finds with a matching ID of type `Guid`:

```
public T GetItemWithGuid(Guid id) => this.AsEnumerable<T>().FirstOrDefault(n => n.ID == id);
```